# How to stop/break the loop in between using Node.js

Tags: node.js

From Bot i have two response start and stop, when i get start for loop is getting executed and when i get stop from the Bot in console i can see the message as "stopped" but after that also for loop is getting executed. I want to stop the loop if anytime i get the message from BOT as stop, below is my code kindly let me know what mistake i am doing.

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
  //console.log("user messages are",context.activity.text);
  //var stop = context.activity.text;
  this.logger.log('Calling QnA Maker');
  const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

  // If an answer was received from QnA Maker, send the answer back to the user.
  if (qnaResults[0]) {
    await context.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);
    var botresponse = qnaResults[0].answer;
    if (botresponse == 'start' || botresponse == 'stop') {
      var i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        console.log("i value is", i);
        console.log("botresponse is", botresponse);
        if (botresponse === 'stop') {
          console.log("stopped");
          break;

        }
        console.log("loop running");
      }

    }

  } else {
    await context.sendActivity('Sorry, I cannot understand you!');
  }
  // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
  await next();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you're using, so not all aspects of your code are clear. It's not typical to `await next()`, you should probably remove `await` from that line. This is unrelated to your main problem. My next comment would be that your formatting is non-standard. I'm going to edit the question to make it more readable for most programmers, is that ok ?

Comment: `break` instead of use `return false`

Comment: @Code Bling: yes please, Thanks for your input

Comment: @yuvarajsekaran can you post a sample of the log that you're seeing?  It will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @Code Bling: From the BOT emulator if i enter START, for loop is getting executed and printing "loop running", while after two times of loop if i enter STOP loop is not breaking it its getting executed 7 times and printing 7 times "loop running" in console, i want to break the loop in-between whenever i want.

Comment: @yuvarajsekaran you only set the response outside of the loop, so whether 'stop' or 'start', it will be the same for whole loop. If you enter STOP it is probably sending another message, so running onMessage function again. You need to make sure that the loop is only called once for every concurrent START message (is a singleton), that it listens for new messages while looping, and that it sleeps/pauses during the loop, otherwise it executes too quickly.

Comment: StackOverflow may not be the best place to get help with something like this

Comment: @CodeBling: Can you suggest how to implement this concept, if the input is start it should call one method continuously until the input is stop

Comment: @yuvarajsekaran move this line `const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);` into the loop